# Swift - Date formatting (DD vs dd)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

What's the difference between using DD and dd in DateFormatter? When searching around, I don't see explicit differences.. Some date format documentation shows "DD" and "dd" and some do not..

I'd like to understand the difference and why it produces the results shown in the comments below:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
print(formatter.string(from: Date())) // 02/32/2017

formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYYY"
print(formatter.string(from: Date())) // 02/01/2017
```

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns is the ultimate reference, and clearly documents both "dd" and "DD". – Btw, you most probably want "yyyy" and not "YYYY".

Answer (score 18):

`DD` is day of year
`dd` is day of month

When in doubt, check the [Unicode reference](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#dfst-day)

Answer (score 5):

`DD` is the `Day of year`
`dd` is the `Day of the month`

For more information see for example
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score -1):

The official Java documentation is the ultimate reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
```

as it differs from the unicode reference:
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#dfst-day